# Is every continuous closed surjection also open?

Tags: general-topology, functions

$f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a continuous closed surjection, $X$ and $Y$ are topological spaces. Is $f$ also open?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you think about the problem: true or false and what is your intuition behind thinking that?

Answer (score 5):

Not necessarily. Let

$$f:[0,3]\to[0,2]:x\mapsto\begin{cases}
x,&\text{if }0\le x\le 2\\
4-x,&\text{if }2\le x\le 3\;.
\end{cases}$$

(This map essentially just folds the last third of the domain back onto the middle third.) Every closed subset of $[0,3]$ is compact, so its image is compact and therefore closed. However, the image of the open set $(2,3]$ in $[0,3]$ is $[1,2)$, which is not open in $[0,2]$.